# How can I filter records returned by a stored procedure call?

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, intersystems-cache-studio

I'm trying to use a stored procedure to search for users in my WinFomrs application. I have this code:

```
Regex regPattern = new Regex(searchTextBox.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = users.GetAllUsers()
                            .Where<users>(item => regPattern.IsMatch(item.FirstName))
                            .ToList<users>();`
```

But it doesn't work, because my `GetAllUsers` in my DAL doesn't have a `where` statement because I used a stored procedure instead of a regular SQL statement so how can I fix this, guys?

Here is my BAL:

```
public List<GetAllUsers> GetAllUsers()
{
    List<GetAllUsers> UserDatails = new List<GetAllUsers>();
    try
    {
        CacheConnection.ClearParameters();
        dataTable = CacheConnection.GetDataTable("AGSP.Users_GetAllUsers2");
        if (dataTable.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow r in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                GetAllUsers oBo = new GetAllUsers();
                Type myType = typeof(GetAllUsers);
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = myType.GetProperties();
                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p in properties)
                {
                    if (dataTable.Columns.Contains(p.Name))
                    {
                        if (ReferenceEquals(r[p.Name], DBNull.Value))
                        {
                            if (p.PropertyType.ToString() == "System.DateTime")
                            {
                                p.SetValue(oBo, DateTime.Now, null);
                            }
                            else if (p.PropertyType.ToString() == "System.String")
                            {
                                p.SetValue(oBo, "", null);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            p.SetValue(oBo, r[p.Name], null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                UserDatails.Add(oBo);
            }
            return UserDatails;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return UserDatails;
}
```

BTW, I'm not using SQL, I'm using Caché programming language for my database but it also has a stored procedure.

I fixed it guys

what i did in my search button is this

```
Regex regPattern = new Regex(searchTextBox.Text);
        lstUsers.DataSource = users.GetAllUsersByUsername(searchTextBox.Text);
```

instead of this

```
Regex regPattern = new Regex(searchTextBox.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = users.GetAllUsers()
                            .Where<users>(item => regPattern.IsMatch(item.FirstName))
                            .ToList<users>();`
```

And also

this is what i did in my DAL

```
public List<GetAllUsers> GetAllUsersByUsername(string username) 
    {
        List<GetAllUsers> UserDatails = new List<GetAllUsers>();
        try
        {
            CacheConnection.ClearParameters();
            CacheConnection.AddParameter("UserName", username);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a stored procedure or a regular `SELECT` statement. What does `GetAllUsers()` return?

Comment: You have two options, a, show us more of your code, and a result set of what you expect vs what you get, and also tell us more about what you need, or b, change your stored proc to include a where clause and pass it a parameter.  using a SQL Call \ Stored Proc without a parameter and a where clause is also bad practice.  What will you do when you hit 1 million or so lines and your data is huge and youre bringing back 1 million results for just one record and create yourself performance issues

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the search value to the stored procedure instead and then instead of returning all users from the query use a statement like '%Search Term%' in a where statement that returns the results.

or you could put a row filter on the data table to filter the results that way. Before you enter your for loop.

this page has a good description on filtering 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx)

this has good example of searching:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/